# how can I make a loop on time series and plot all them together in R?

Tags: r, loops, plot, time-series

i've just started using R and some problems with time series analysis occured. Namely, I have data base concerned different products = different product launch id  and I want to plot all of time series (x - weeks_since_launch, y - units_that_sold_that_week) with different colors, presented on one plot. There is also a need before to make a loop and signalize to R to take new time series after 26 weeks_since_launch. Thats how a piece of my data base looks like: https://imageshack.com/i/euhh3kj

I am sorry that I cannot even post a code, because I have no idea how to make it.

I would be enormously grateful for any help.

Comment: I suggest you remove "urgent" from the title. And post some code, data, and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you need, but maybe this will work?

```
test <- data.frame(Product_Launch_Id = factor(c(rep(1,26), rep(2,26))),
                   Weeks_Since_Launch = rep(1:26, 2),
                   Units_that_sold_that_week = c(rnorm(52, 50, 20)))


library(ggplot2)
ggplot(test, aes(x = Weeks_Since_Launch, y = Units_that_sold_that_week)) + geom_line(aes(colour =Product_Launch_Id), size = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you just explain to me, what the numbers in bracket mean? I would like to present 2000 of products in one plot

Comment: What numbers in bracket? You can do it with how many series you wany. the only problem is that if you have series with big diefferences in "Units_that_sold_that_week" it won't be possible because you cant create 2000 different Y scales in one plot (two maximum). It is also will be very hard to look at 2061 different lines

Comment: One question more: cause you used rnorm to present Units_that_sold_that_week, what if I want to use not rnorm but the exact number which is in data base?

Comment: It will work. I just used `rnorm` cause i didn't want to enter your data manually. just remmebr that if your time series are very differ from one another, it will be impossible to plot them on one plot

Comment: Ok, thanks! but if i want to get the number of Units_that_sold_that_week which function should I use after = ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. in order reproduce this with your data, you just need to put your datas name into `ggplot` and makes sure that Product_Launch_Id is a factor that's all. (you don't need to reproduce my data set)

Comment: before i use  Units_that_sold_that_week only in ggplot function, shouldn't i define what Units_that_sold_that_week means? in code you wrote Units_that_sold_that_week are defined by rnorm, I want to take values from database but using only the name of the column in ggplot returns error

Comment: You don't need to define it. Just insert it as is. I defined it because I needed to create a new dataset. You already have a datset

Comment: Ok, now i understood you. And understood that this answer is not exactly what I am searching for, because before putting time series into plot, I need to create a loop.

Comment: Why do you need a loop??? just switch `ggplot(test, aes(x = Weeks_Since_Launch, y = Units_that_sold_that_week)) + geom_line(aes(colour =Product_Launch_Id), size = 3)` to `ggplot(YorData, aes(x = Weeks_Since_Launch, y = Units_that_sold_that_week)) + geom_line(aes(colour =Product_Launch_Id), size = 3)` where "YourData" is your data

Comment: with the code: ggplot(szeregi, aes(x = Weeks_Since_Launch, y = Units_that_sold_that_week)) + geom_line(aes(colour =Product_Launch_Id), size = 1) I got this kind of plot http://imageshack.com/a/img845/9798/cj7n.jpg but I need time series - after every 26 in the column Weeks_Since_Launch I want R to draw new time series

Comment: Thats why I told you that Product_Launch_Id has to be a factor. do: `szeregi$Product_Launch_Id <- factor(szeregi$Product_Launch_Id)` and then run the `ggplot` again

Comment: Sorry for my incompetence and misunderstanding... Now it works.

Comment: Np, glad I could help